# Accuracy optimized in WEKA WrapperSubsetEval?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I'm using WEKA via the GUI. When running WrapperSubsetEval with J48 and BestFirst on a classification problem,I see that the tool optimizes by default for Accuracy in case of discrete class. How is this Accuracy  formally defined?

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy is the number of instances the classifier classified correctly out of all instances it classified.

More formally:
(# of correct classifications)/(# of correct and wrong classifications)

I think you should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall